# How to add output of second query and third query with the output of First Query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, count, sum

In a table you have product_id and order_created_date which is a datetimestamp field.

Now we required output as below.

For each product_id how many orders are created today, how many orders are created last 5 days, how many orders are created last 30 days, total no of orders created till today

```
Product_Id orders_today orders_last5days orders_last30days total_orders_tilltoday
101             5              20              100                 250
102             7              27              150                 450
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the counts are cumulative. Thus, for product 101, there are 5 orders today that are included in the last 5 days and 25 orders are included in the last 30days.

I counted all product_id in the Product then call a subquery to count per today, since 5days and since 30 days. Note that I used dummy count (for ex: 0 as orders_today) as since UNION ALL requires all columns to be the same name.

At the end, I total (sum) per product id. Note that the total order count is repeated so no need to get the total.

```
MATCH (n:Product)  
WITH n.product_id as Product_Id, count(n) as total_orders_tilltoday 
WITH Product_Id, total_orders_tilltoday ORDER BY Product_Id
CALL {
    WITH Product_Id
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Product {product_id: Product_Id}) 
    WHERE  duration.inDays(date(n.order_created_date), date()).days <= 30
    WITH n.product_id as Product_Id, count(n) as orders_last30days
    RETURN   0 as orders_today, 0 as orders_last5days, orders_last30days 
    UNION ALL
    WITH Product_Id
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Product {product_id: Product_Id}) 
    WHERE  duration.inDays(date(n.order_created_date), date()).days <= 5
    WITH n.product_id as Product_Id, count(n) as orders_last5days
    RETURN   0 as orders_today, orders_last5days, 0 as orders_last30days 
    UNION ALL
    WITH Product_Id
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Product {product_id: Product_Id}) 
    WHERE  duration.inDays(date(n.order_created_date), date()).days <= 1
    WITH n.product_id as Product_Id, count(n) as orders_today
    RETURN  orders_today, 0 as orders_last5days, 0 as orders_last30days  
}
RETURN Product_Id,sum(orders_today) as orders_today,sum(orders_last5days) as orders_last5days,sum(orders_last30days) as orders_last30days,total_orders_tilltoday)
```

Sample Result using 3 product ids:

```
╒════════════╤══════════════╤══════════════════╤═══════════════════╤════════════════════════╕
│"Product_Id"│"orders_today"│"orders_last5days"│"orders_last30days"│"total_orders_tilltoday"│
╞════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│101         │0             │0                 │2                  │2                       │
├────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│102         │0             │1                 │1                  │1                       │
├────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│103         │1             │1                 │1                  │1                       │
└────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: If i try the above method i am getting error at CALL that Invalid input '{':expected whitespace, namespace of a procedure name(line 4, column 5(offset:163)) 
"CALL{"

Comment: what is your version of neo4j?  subquery call is for version 4 and above only.